# Why is min_element() returning the index of the minimum element, instead of an iterator?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

`min_element()` is supposed to return a pointer pointing to the minimum element in a array or vector, but here it is returning a position of the element with minimum value. Why is this happening?
Sorry for this silly question i am a beginner.

```
int n; cin>>n;
vector<int> arr(n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>arr[i];

int minElementIndex = min_element(arr.begin(),arr.end()) - arr.begin();
cout<<minElementIndex;
```

Comment: *why is it returning a position of the element with minimum value* -- It isn't doing that.  Look at the line more carefully.  There is more going on than just a call to `std::min_element`

Comment: What do you think that subtracting `arr.begin()` from the iterator given by `min_element()` does?

Comment: Just wanted to say that there shouldn't be downvoting of this question - while it *is* a simple mistake, the question is decently formed and has a minimally reproducible code snippet.

Answer (score 5):

`min_element` returns an iterator (not necessarily a pointer) to the element. It does so here as well.

But you are not printing the return value of the `min_element` call. You are first subtracting the iterator to the beginning of `arr` from it (`- arr.begin()`).

Subtracting (random-access) iterators of a container (or pointers into the same array) results in an integer with value equal to the distance between the iterators or pointer. So if you subtract an iterator to the beginning, you get the index of the element as integer.

Answer (score 1):

You are subtracting a pointer from another in your call to `min_element`. Try this approach rather:

```
    int index;
    int n; cin >> n;
    vector<int> arr(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    int minElementValue = *std::min_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == minElementValue) {
            index = i;


        }
    }

    cout << minElementValue << ":" ;
    cout << "  " << index;
```